# Function keystrokes 'ate' by host when running Win7 in a VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard

I'm a recent Mac convert, but still need to use Windows for work related tasks. A man's gotta eat & pay for internet access.

I have VirtualBox setup w/ a Windows 7 VM. The VM has Visual Studio 2008 installed, along w/ various needed utilities. Everything works great or as expected except for the fact that pressing most of the F keys (F1-F12, excluding F5 & F6) are intercepted by the host OS and processed. I know you can press Command+Fn+F to accomplish this; however, a lot of quick access commands are assigned to the F-keys. (Especially F9-F11 for debugging). These are accessed quite often and the 3 finger combo gets old, fast.

Question:  Is there anyway w/ VirtualBox to, perhaps only in full screen mode, to have the host OS pass those through or otherwise not process them w/o the need for Command+Fn?

I've tried googling but haven't had much success.

TIA

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no. However, if you have a full size keyboard, there's a second `Fn` key to the right of the `Delete` key which can be used in place of the `Command+Fn` combination.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I know that VMWare Fusion can catch the F-keystrokes before the host OS in single window / fullscreen mode ([not in the unity mode, though](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11656/how-to-send-keyboard-combination-that-is-global-shortcut-in-os-x-to-virtual-mac)).

Comment: @Randolph, many thanks. I wasn't aware of that. That is so much better. You should convert that to an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: I have done as requested :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 10.6 and a USB keyboard, the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys pass through to the app; OS-X only intercepts the media functions.

In your OS-X's Keyboard SysPrefs pane, is:

> Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard
>   function keys

selected?

With this selection, my (unshifted) F-keys pass straight through to my VBox VM.  With it unselected, I need to use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to generate type them (even within OS-X).

Answer (score 3):

also note that in Keyboard ==> Keyboard shortcuts ==> "Mission Control" settings disable F11 and F12 for show desktop and show gadgets, excuse me, show dashboard.

Comment: This is a must in addition to the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

Not that I'm aware of, no. However, if you have a full size keyboard, there's a second <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to the right of the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key which can be used in place of the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> combination.

Comment: Many thanks. It's good to know I have this option at least when connected to ext monitor/keyboard.